# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function with docker

Tags: python, cython

The crypto.so file written by another person is being used in Python.

There is no problem with using it in normal centos desktop (gcc, gcc-c++ together).

However, the dynamic module error occurs even if you proceed with the same operation in the centos installed by docker.

I can't check the so file's contents.

Why does this error occur?

Didn't I install some of the necessary packages?

(Python, path and other environmental variables is using exactly the same.)

And strangely, there is an error in the first import, but there is no error in the next import.(Of course the program is not working because it is not a normal import)

```
>>> import crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/crypto.pyx", line 5, in init lib.crypto (./lib/crypto.c:2336)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initCrypto)
>>> import crypto
>>>
```

Also, check the module with dir, the results were different from the normal import.

```
# abnormal import
>>> dir(crypto)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'base64']
# normal import
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'base64', '__file__', '__test__', 'AES', ...]
>>>
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  smartta:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: my_image
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    container_name: my_container
    volumes:
      - ./my_project:/app/my_project
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.system
    ports:
      - "15001:15001"
```

my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}"


RUN yum -y update \
    && yum -y install curl bzip2 gcc make gcc-c++ automake which python-devel \
    && yum -y groupinstall "development tools"
    && curl -sSL https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/anaconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/anaconda.sh -bf \
    && rm -rf /tmp/anaconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update -n base -c defaults conda \
    && conda update --all \
    && conda clean --all --yes \
    && rpm -e --nodeps curl bzip2 \
    && yum clean all \
    && conda create --name SmartTA python=2.7.13 -y \
    && conda init


... install requirements ...



COPY ./compose/start /start
RUN chmod +x /start
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib


ENTRYPOINT ["/start"]
```

anyway, I'm testing using docker exec ~~ /bin/bash

Comment: This is usually that you're trying to use a Python 3 module on Python 2 (or vice versa). It isn't obvious to be where you're getting the module from though...

Comment: And there is `initCrypto` in crypto.so? I.e. `nm crypto.so` shows one. If not it was built for a wrong version. What is the python version for which this import works?

Answer (score 0):

Because the package is not available inside the docker centos

Install it inside docker

`docker exec -it my_containers_name /bin/bash`

This will open the docker she'll and see what is installed in it

Comment: no, package is in container using volumes (mount) with docker-compose

Comment: Add your docker file and docker compose file

Comment: If pip is installed then directly install pip install crypto from the docker shell

Comment: crypto.so is an unopened module. It's not registered on the pip.

Comment: and crypto.so is in my_project folder

Comment: That's a package with the same name only. crypto.so is another package made by someone I know. It's a paid package, so I can't see what's inside.